# Paper trail controller as meta data does not work. (Ruby 2.3.3, Rails 4.2 and paper_trail 5.2.3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paper-trail-gem

Following the steps to capture information from the controller as meta data does not work. (Ruby 2.3.3, Rails 4.2 and paper_trail 5.2.3)

## model

```
has_paper_trail only: [:status]
```

## migrate

```
class AddHotelToVersions < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        add_reference :versions, :hotel, index: true, foreign_key: true, null: false
        add_column :versions, :ip, :string, null: false
        add_column :versions, :user_agent, :string, null: false
    end
end
```

## controller

```
def info_for_paper_trail
    { hotel_id: current_user.hotel.id, ip: request.remote_ip, user_agent: request.user_agent }
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it upgrading paper trails to 6.0.2